# Html5 video player in iPad

Tags: android, ios, html, ipad, video

I am trying to play a mp4 video in my hybrid app for ipad. From my app requesting the server for the video and getting as video/mp4 stream. Which is playing in browsers and android devices but not working in iOS devices. Used below code to play the video.

```
<video id="tour-video" preload="" controls="" poster="img/poster.jpg">
<source src="http://www.example.com/API/getVideo" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Code seems correct, Are the server delivering the video with the correct MIME type?

Comment: yes MIME type set to 'video/mp4'.

Comment: Maybe there's problem with the encoding of the video.

Comment: I kept that same video file locally and tried which played without any issue.